# How to call a constructor within a second constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I have been instructed to:

- Create a second Parrot constructor which takes an Integer as its only argument.
- Call the other constructor providing "Polly" as the name, and the Integer argument as the age.

Within this method:

```
public class Parrot extends Omnivore
{   

Parrot()   
{
    name = "Billy";
    age = 6;
    noise = "Argh!";
}    
Parrot(int i)   
{
    i = age;
    //Call other constructor providing "Polly" as name?

} 

}
```

I'm a little confused on how to do this, I've never really came across calling multiple constructors before so any help on how this would be done would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you don't have a constructor that will accept `"Polly"`.

Comment: Easy: you can't, just in the first line by this().

Comment: Also, all of those other methods have nothing to do with your question.  So please don't include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one, make a constructor that takes a `String` and an `int`.

```
Parrot(String name, int age)   
{
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Step two, call that constructor with a hardcoded default `name` and an `age` provided. Use `this`. Like

```
Parrot(int i)   
{
    this("Polly", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This process is used when we want to perform multiple tasks in a single constructor rather than creating a code for each task in a single constructor we create a separate constructor for each task and make their chain which makes the program more readable
using this method you can

lets see class Temp example

```
 class Temp 
{ 
// default constructor 1 
// default constructor will call another constructor 
// using this keyword from same class 
Temp() 
{ 
    // calls constructor 2 
    this(5); 
    System.out.println("The Default constructor"); 
} 

// parameterized constructor 2 
Temp(int x) 
{ 
    // calls constructor 3 
    this(5, 15); 
    System.out.println(x); 
} 

// parameterized constructor 3 
Temp(int x, int y) 
{ 
    System.out.println(x * y); 
} 

public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    // invokes default constructor first 
    new Temp(); 
} 
}
```